# Linux shell command to copy text data from a file to another

Tags: linux, shell, text, command

**file_1 contents:**
aaa 111 222 333
bbb 444 555 666
ccc 777 888 999

**file_2 contents:**
ddd
eee
fff

**how do i copy only part of the text from file_1 to file_2

so that file_2 would become:**
ddd 111 222 333
eee 444 555 666
fff 777 888 999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$2FS$3FS$4;next} {print $0, a[FNR]}' file_1 file_2
```

Explanation:

`NR` is the current input line, `FNR` is the number of input line in current file, you can see that by

```
$ awk '{print NR,FNR}' file_1 file_2
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 1
5 2
6 3
```

So, the condition `NR==FNR` is only true when reading the first file, and that's when the columns `$2`, `$3`, and `$4` get saved in `a[FNR]`. After reading `file_1`, the condition `NR==FNR` becomes false and the block `{print $0, a[FNR]}` is executed, where `$0` is the whole line in `file_2`.

Comment: what if the text to copy are not length-fixed? i mean, like a text string which have variable text fields not necessarily 4, and i want to copy all the text field except the first.

Comment: @ray Same story. The variables `$1`, `$2`, etc are the fields in the line. All `awk` cares about is the field separator, that by default is is one or more whitespaces. The fields themselves can be strings of variable length.